# PHP Login Script Session not surviving

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

I'm having issues with a simple login system that I'm trying to create. Here is my setup:

index.php

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
session_start();
//present login form with action=login.php
} else {
//display actual page
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
} else {
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=sha1($_POST['password']);
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","database",3306,"/tmp/mysql.sock");
$query="SELECT * FROM login WHERE `name`='".$username."' AND `passwordhash`='".$password."' LIMIT 1";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
            session_start();
    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['firstname']=$row['firstname'];
    $_SESSION['lastname']=$row['lastname'];
    echo "Username: ". $_SESSION['username']." Name: ".$_SESSION['firstname']." ".$_SESSION['lastname']; //this is just here as POC. If I redirect to index.php (using header()), it shows the login form (claims $_SESSION['username'] is unset).
}
}
?>
```

Once I log in, it shows my username and first and last names just fine on login.php (not a database problem). But if I redirect to index.php, it shows the login form immediately. What's the issue?
EDIT: Even after adding session_start() to login.php, the same outcome results.

Comment: You must also call `session_start()` on `login.php`.

Comment: Call `session_start();` before you use `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make session_start() the very first line of your file it must be included in all files that use session variables

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't realized it needed to be called in every single file that uses session variables - it seemed to me that the session would endure regardless of file. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help make sure to check this answer if it solved your problem

Comment: I will as soon as it lets me. I still have 5 minutes until I can mark an answer.